# How do I get around a zip archive that was already closed in python?

Tags: python, zip

I have created a script to back up a user specified folder to a user specified location as a zip file, I can run the script once just fine but if I run the script again and use the same argument for the zip file name I get the error below.

```
Attempt to write to ZIP archive that was already closed
```

Zip file code below:

```
bkZip = zipfile.ZipFile(backZip, 'w') # Not sure what to say for lines 26 - 31
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(backUp): 
    bkZip.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        bkZip.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    bkZip.close()
```

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this and need a little bit of help.

Comment: is `bkZip.close()` really supposed to be indented inside the top level loop? That seems obviously wrong, but also something that could be a product of copying your code into the Stack Overflow editor, rather than the cause of the problem in your real code. If that line really is like that, I'd expect your back up to fail anytime there was a sub-folder in the `backUp` location (regardless of how many times you run the script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(backUp):
    bkZip.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        bkZip.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
bkZip.close()
```

Comment: Thank you just got to fix a "File already exists error"

and an issue of it backing my folder up as

`zipfile://home/akeno/Desktop/BootStrap/`

instead of 

`zipfile://BootStrap/`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly you want to happen.

You could check if a file with the target filename already exists, then change the name (to say, my_zip_file.zip.old) or just delete it:

```
if os.path.exists(foo):
    os.remove(foo)
```

Or you could print a warning and ask the user to delete the existing archive or abort.

Or, if your intent was to append to the archive, you could:

- Extract everything from the old backup
- Delete the existing backup
- Then write the combination of old backup and current output to the new archive

Comment: The plan was to check and see if target filename already exists and then delete it to make a new test.zip

Comment: Well this deletes the file, but the script moves the file to another directory, that is specified by the user. So how do I make it delete said file in specified directory

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KQbWQFVW  this is the entire script to look at. McGrady's answer fixed my main question, but my side question of removing the file after being moved via script is an issue I can't seem to solve.

Comment: Instead of using `shutil.move()` to get the archive where you want it to be, why not create it in the right place straight away? As in `bkZip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(dest, backZip), 'w'). This would also avoid the current issue of having to check two locations for potential older backups.

Comment: Okay but then how do I check dest, backZip with if os.path.exists(foo):

Comment: Replace `foo` with `os.path.join(dest, backZip)`, or store that location in some additional variable.

Comment: Thank you mate, I forgot all about being able to use os.path.join now I just have one other issue to fix and that is where it saves as 

`zipfile://home/akeno/Desktop/BootStrap/`

instead of 

`zipfile://BootStrap/`

Comment: You could take the relative path from the root of the backup, like so `shortdirname = os.path.relpath(dirname, backup)`. And then use `shortdirname` instead of `dirname` in the part where you add the files to the archive.

Comment: And now I am confused lol, I'm still fairly new to python I've been googling this issue for days now if not weeks.